# Openlayers 3 pan map always to the left

Tags: rotation, openlayers-3, pan

I am developing an app where I get a user location from the server and I display it on the map.

I am also provided with an angle so I can display in which direction the user is looking.

There is also a possibility to open a sidepanel for some more information. In this situation I have to move the map center left which I do like this.

```
var center = map.getView().getCenter();

var pan = ol.animation.pan({
    duration: 500,
    source: (center)
});

if (isSidePanelVisible) {
    center[0] += 1000;
} else {
    center[0] -= 1000;
}

map.beforeRender(pan);
map.getView().setCenter(center);
```

This works great while the user is "looking" north but not when I rotate the map by an angle. Is there a quick way to pan the map always left by a certain amount regardles of angle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [ol.Map.html#getPixelFromCoordinate](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Map.html#getPixelFromCoordinate) to convert the center to pixel coordinates, do your calculation and then convert back to real coordinates with [ol.Map.html#getCoordinateFromPixel](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Map.html#getCoordinateFromPixel):

```
var view = map.getView();
var center = view.getCenter();
var centerInPx = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(center);
var newCenterInPx = [centerInPx[0] - 100, centerInPx[1]];
var newCenter = map.getCoordinateFromPixel(newCenterInPx);
view.setCenter(newCenter);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6mh110xv/1/

Comment: this works great ! , To pan left , right , bottom , top , you can refer the below answer.

Answer (score 0):

To pan left , right , bottom , top , you can use the following code :

```
panMap(direction: string) {
    let newCenterInPx;
    let center = map.getView().getCenter();
    let centerInPx = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(center);

    switch (direction) {
      case 'left': newCenterInPx = [centerInPx[0] - 100, centerInPx[1]]; break;
      case 'right': newCenterInPx = [centerInPx[0] + 100, centerInPx[1]]; break;
      case 'top': newCenterInPx = [centerInPx[0], centerInPx[1] - 100]; break;
      case 'bottom': newCenterInPx = [centerInPx[0], centerInPx[1] + 100]; break;
    }
    var newCenter = map.getCoordinateFromPixel(newCenterInPx);
    map.getView().setCenter(newCenter);

  }
```